# Porque Fonte com Serifa é tão pouco usada na Web e em Aplicativos?

Tags: html, css, ux, acessibilidade, ui

<sup>*Não busco respostas baseadas em opinião*!</sup>

Outro dia eu vi um [Kindle](https://www.amazon.com.br/kindle), e reparei que ele usava por padrão um `font-family` com *serifa*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
<sub>*[O que é fonte com serifa](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serifa)*</sub>

Depois disso eu fiquei me perguntado. A Amazon, com certeza teve um bom motivo para escolher uma *fonte com serifa* para esse aparelho... Mas porque?
 
<sub>*(sei que o usuário deve ter uma opção para trocar a fonte, mas não é o foco aqui)*</sub>

- Porque é tão raro vermos *Fontes Serifadas* na web e principalmente nos Aplicativos em geral?
- **Existe alguma contra indicação para usar esse estilo** tipográfico em telas? Ele prejudica a acessibilidade de alguma forma?
- Qual seria a intenção e o que poderia ter motivado a Amazon a optar por esse tipo de fonte com serifa no Kindle, já que na web esse estilo é tão incomum?

> **OBS:** Certamente existe algum motivo técnico para isso, então seriam bem vindas resposta que **NÃO** sejam baseadas em "opinião pessoal"!

Comment: Excelente pergunta jovem, sempre vejo fontes serifadas em material impresso e sem serifas e leitura digital. Vou acompanhar as respostas.

Answer (score 1):

As fontes do tipo Serif, ou serifadas, são indicadas para livros e texto grandes impressos, pois auxiliam na leitura, dando uma maior continuidade e sem causar cansaço visual.

Já as fontes Sans Serif, ou não serifadas, são adequadas para títulos, chamadas e textos digitais.

Isso porque, quando visualizamos um texto na tela de um computador, tablet ou celular, as Serifas acabam sendo um empecilho para a fluidez da leitura.

Levando em conta que o Kindle foi feito para simular um livro, então ele se adequa no tipo livros e texto grandes impressos.

Fonte: https://blog.trakto.io/psicologia-da-tipografia-fonte/

Comment: Será que estas considerações, plenamente aplicáveis à tecnologia dos monitores de 20 anos atrás, continuam ainda aplicáveis considerando a atual resolução dos monitores dos computadores?

Comment: A maioria dos sites hoje em dia possuem fontes não serifadas, por mais que eles usem fontes serifadas para o kindle o site da Amazon não usa fonte com serifa, então acredito que isto é totalmente aplicável hoje em dia mesmo com a mudança dos monitores.

Comment: Acho que o que o Anônimo quis dizer que com resoluções maiores as fontes serifadas são melhor renderizadas nas telas. Algo que não acontecia no monitores antigos, onde as fontes serifadas ficavam "pixeladas" e com péssima leiturabilidade.... Agora, se as resoluções de tela mais altas de hoje em dia favorecem o uso de fontes serifadas, eu acredito que sim, tudo bem... mas porque elas ainda são pouco usadas? Eu não sei dizer, deve haver algum motivo mais atual para essa explicação... Ou... não deve ser esse o único motivo...

Comment: Eu gostei bastante desse comparativo aqui: https://tutano.trampos.co/12742-infografico-tipografia-serifa/ nele consta que a resolução de um texto impresso é de 1000dp1 , em um monitor normal apenas cerca de 100dp1, e mesmo na tela de retina do iphone temos apenas 300dp1, com isso entendo que a indicação de usar fontes sem serifa no ambiente digital ainda é valida.